# MutableStatOf Data Class not creating re-composition in Composable

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-viewmodel

I am struggling to understand what is the best way to get this to work.
I have some input fields and I created a TextFieldState to keep all the state in one place.
But it is not triggering a re-composition of the composable so the state never updates.
I saw this stack overflow answer on a similar question, but I just find it confusing and it doesn't make sense to me

Here is the code:

The Composable:

@Composable
fun AddTrip (
addTripVm: AddTripVm = hiltViewModel()
) {

```
var name = addTripVm.getNameState()
var stateTest = addTripVm.getStateTest()

Column(
    //verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxSize()
) {
    Text(text = "Add Trip")
    Column(

    ){

        println("From Composable: ${name.value.value}") //No Recomposition
        meTextField(
            value = name.value.value,
            onChange = {
                addTripVm.updateName(it)
            },
            placeholder = "Name",
        )
```

}

View Model code:

```
@HiltViewModel
class AddTripVm @Inject constructor(
    private val tripRepository: TripRepositoryContract,
    private val tripValidator: TripValidatorContract
): TripValidatorContract by tripValidator,  ViewModel() {

    /**
     * Name of the trip, this is required
     */
    private val nameState: MutableState<TextFieldState> = mutableStateOf(TextFieldState())

    private var stateTest = mutableStateOf("");

    fun updateStateTest(newValue: String) {
        stateTest.value = newValue
    }

    fun getStateTest(): MutableState<String> {
        return stateTest
    }

    fun getNameState(): MutableState<TextFieldState> {
        return nameState;
    }

    fun updateName(name: String) {
        println("From ViewModel? $name") 
        nameState.value.value = name
        println("From ViewModel after update: ${nameState.value.value}") //Updates perfectly
    }

}
```

Text field state:

```
data class TextFieldState(
    var value: String = "",
    var isValid: Boolean? = null,
    var errorMessage: String? = null
)
```

Is this possible? Or do I need to separate the value as a string and keep the state separate for if its valid or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't change instance of nameState's value with

```
 nameState.value.value = name
```

It's the same object which State checks by default with

```
fun <T> structuralEqualityPolicy(): SnapshotMutationPolicy<T> =
    StructuralEqualityPolicy as SnapshotMutationPolicy<T>

private object StructuralEqualityPolicy : SnapshotMutationPolicy<Any?> {
    override fun equivalent(a: Any?, b: Any?) = a == b

    override fun toString() = "StructuralEqualityPolicy"
}
```

MutableState use this as

```
fun <T> mutableStateOf(
    value: T,
    policy: SnapshotMutationPolicy<T> = structuralEqualityPolicy()
): MutableState<T> = createSnapshotMutableState(value, policy)
```

Easiest way is to set

```
nameState.value = nameState.value.copy(value= name)
```

other option is to write your own `SnapshotMutationPolicy`

Comment: Thanks, I am still very new to Kotlin/Android & I am not sure how easy it will be for me to write my own policy. But nameState.value = nameState.value.copy(value= name) worked perfectly. I need more practice with Kotlin and Android

Comment: i'm not able to try out the code at the moment, there are so many `value` parameters is bit confusing. What you should do is update your `MutableState` value with a new object. Data class have `copy` function that creates a new object with the parameter you specified. My snippet above changed String while yours was a TextField.

Comment: Your solution worked perfectly, but I just one question: Is there any performance penalty to this? Constantly copying a data class? Or Is it better to keep the value as a separate string? And keep the errors as separate state?

Comment: No, not really. Unlike Views, in compose some methods require to create new objects for each recomposition. Modifier.offset{} for instance uses IntOffset, draw methods use Offset objects that you can only initially set properties. and Rect objects and so on.