# Why does encapsulating my state prevent recomposition from happening?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

My MainActivity.kt:

```kotlin
class StateViewModel : ViewModel() {
    var state = MutableStateFlow("clicks: ")
}

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            PlaygroundTheme {
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
                ) {
                    Greeting()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun Greeting(svm : StateViewModel = viewModel()) {
    var state = svm.state.collectAsState()
    Text(
        text = state.value
    )
    Button(onClick = { svm.state.value += "x" }) {
        Text(
            text = "click me"
        )
    }
}
```

The code works as intended, that is if I click the button 3 times, the text says: `"clicks: xxx"`.

However if I encapsulate the state into a data class as below, clicking the button has no effect:

```
data class State(var text: String = "clicks count: ") {
}

class StateViewModel : ViewModel() {
    var state = MutableStateFlow(State())
}

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            PlaygroundTheme {
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
                ) {
                    Greeting()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun Greeting(svm : StateViewModel = viewModel()) {
    var state = svm.state.collectAsState()
    Text(
        text = state.value.text
    )
    Button(onClick = { svm.state.value.text += "x" }) {
        Text(
            text = "click me"
        )
    }
}
```

I expected this to work, because `equals()` is auto-generated for data classes, so Jetpack should recognize that the state has changed. Apparently not, but I don't understand why.

Comment: Does this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72844289/6819340?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The text is not recomposing because the `clciksCount` property of the state is updated directly instead of the state itself, and therefore it won't trigger a state change.

Here is an example of how to fix this issue:

1. The state class should only contain immutable properties and therefore not being changed directly, but by creating a copy of the state class from state holder instead, which is the ViewModel in this case. I suggest keeping the values of the state prefix free.

```kotlin
data class State(
    val clicksCount: String = ""
)
```

2. Inside the ViewModel, the mutable state must remain private, because the UI should not change the state directly. For that reason, there is an additional public immutable property available for observation by the UI. Therefore, changing the state must be delegated to the ViewModel, by a simple call from the UI.

```kotlin
class StateViewModel : ViewModel() {

    private val _state = MutableStateFlow(State())
    val state = _state.asStateFlow()

    fun incrementClicksCount() {

        _state.update { currentState ->

            // Increment the clicks count.
            val newClicksCount = currentState.clicksCount + "x"

            // Update the state with the new clicks count.
            currentState.copy(clicksCount = newClicksCount)

        }

    }

}
```

3. Finally, inside the UI, the immutable state is collected in a lifecycle manner, and the callback for incrementing the `clicksCount` property of the state is delegated to the ViewModel.

```kotlin
@Composable
fun Greeting(
    svm: StateViewModel = viewModel()
) {

    // Collecting the state in a lifecycle manner.
    val state by svm.state.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .padding(16.dp),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(16.dp, Alignment.CenterVertically),
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ) {

        Text(text = "Clicks count: ${state.clicksCount}")

        Button(
            onClick = svm::incrementClicksCount, // Delegating the incrementing to the ViewModel.
            content = { Text(text = "Click me") }
        )

    }

}
```

I highly recommend checking out [ViewModel and State in Compose](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/basic-android-kotlin-compose-viewmodel-and-state).

Happy Coding!